# window.open() without title nor toolbar, nothing but content-

Tags: javascript, html, popup, title

im trying to open a popup with nothing but the content using javascript in html.
no status bar, no toolbar, no scrollbars, ...,  and NO TITLE BAR.

The code must work with Internet Explorer, but the more the better in this case...
i know there are some properties sushi as toolbar=no status=no.. but what about title=no?

It isn't really necessary to use window.open, but i must work with javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried searching for `modeless/chromeless javascript window`?

Comment: You came too late. This works a couple of years ago with a bug in MSIE(opening a window in fullscreen-mode and the resize it).  It was called "chromeless window", fortunately this bug has been fixed very soon. If the use of HTA is an option, there you can create windows without any bar.

Comment: If all you're looking for is a popup, then perhaps an absolutely positioned `iframe` or `div` in the body with a large z-index will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want a popup without any way for the user to control that popup (moving the window, minimizing, closing, etc)? This goes against all usability guidelines on the web.

If you still want to do something like this, I would recommend an inline lightbox. This would allow you to control the styling of the popup, however it wouldn't ever leave your site's main window.

A popular solution for this that has a lot of work already completed would be [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).

If you don't need all of the power or functionality of colorbox, it would be pretty easy to roll your own since you have no desire to show any controls.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(document).append('<iframe id="chromelessPopup" src="popup_src.html"></iframe>');
}
```

And then some CSS to style your popup:

```
#chromelessPopup {
    height: 400px; 
    width: 340px; 
    border: 2px solid #000; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10%; 
    left: 35%
}
```

Comment: This appears to fail, since in spite of the "position: absolute" the iframe is hidden when an attempt is made to display it outside of the browser window!

Answer (score 1):

IE has Kiosk Mode (F11 or -k on the command line) but this mode cannot be invoked by webpages for obvious security reasons. Hiding everything (taskbar, etc) from the user's view by a website is clearly not desirable. All popups opened by webpages have a title bar.

Answer (score 0):

I've got some documentation that says there is a `titlebar=no` option to `window.open()` and that IE also supports `fullscreen=yes`.

Note that I haven't tried these.

Comment: No options seem to suppress the title and address bars in Firefox. This is needed for certain applications, such as a clock.